# LDAP Credentials being logged from thrown exceptions

Tags: laravel, logging, ldap

Inside my laravel application, when a binding exception, or any LDAP exception occurs it prints my credentials to the log:

```
[2016-07-14 19:30:35] local.ERROR: exception 'BindException' with message 'Can't contact LDAP server'
Stack trace:
#0 Guard.php(102): ldap_bind('admin', 'password', '', '@corp.acme.org')
```

Is there a way to avoid this rather then catching all exceptions?

Maybe a way to 'pre-hash' the password to send through the bind request so it's not readable from the logs? Is this possible?

Or is this something I shouldn't be worried about because the logs are only accessible from people who have physical / remote access to the server?

Comment: What's the code surrounding the `ldap_bind`? I'd say this is definitely a security risk by letting it be logged. Is it in a try/catch block?

Comment: No, but the bind is covered by an @ symbol to supress errors though: `if(!@$this->connection->bind($username, $password)) { throw Exception(); }`